# Insight on speeding up array formulas (SCAN)

Tags: excel, performance, solver, spill-range

I have a formula system to predict values based on a mathematical model and then calculate a square sum of the error with empirical data. I'm using the solver to minimize the error but the whole process is quite slow. I'm seeking insight on how to improve calculation speed.

**Defined named functions:** (sheet name is `'100DN'`)

P_Th: *(The slow one)*

```
=VSTACK(INDEX('100DN'!P_AU;1);SCAN(INDEX('100DN'!P_AU;1);INDEX('100DN'!T_AU;SEQUENCE(COUNT('100DN'!T_AU)-1;;2))-INDEX('100DN'!T_AU;SEQUENCE(COUNT('100DN'!T_AU)-1));LAMBDA(p;dt;EXP(-dt/'100DN'!$M$9)*(p-INDEX('100DN'!P_AU;1))+(1-EXP(-dt/'100DN'!$M$9))*'100DN'!$M$5*('100DN'!$M$2)+INDEX('100DN'!P_AU;1))))
```

**formulas in Worksheet**

$M$10: `=SUMSQ(P_TH-P_AU)`

**Solver Parameters**

Solving method GCG Nonlinear, defaults settings

Target Minimize $M$10

by changing values in `$M$5;$M$9`

$M$5: `>=.00001`, initial value set near to solution

$M$9: `>=.00001`, initial value set near to solution

Make unconstraint variable non-negative checkbox activated

**Notes on sample & Data Sample**

`P_AU` and `T_AU` are precalculated

$M$2 is constant at `-0.1`

T_AU :

```
0,004
0,054
0,104
0,154
0,204
0,254
0,304
0,354
0,404
0,454
0,504
0,554
0,604
0,654
0,704
0,753
0,803
0,853
0,904
0,955
1,004
1,054
1,104
1,154
1,203
1,254
1,305
1,355
1,404
1,454
1,504
1,553
1,603
1,654
1,704
1,755
1,805
1,854
1,904
1,954
2,004
2,055
2,104
2,154
2,204
2,253
2,303
2,354
2,404
2,455
2,505
2,555
2,604
2,654
2,704
2,754
2,805
2,854
2,904
2,954
3,004
3,053
3,104
3,154
3,204
3,254
3,304
3,354
3,404
3,454
3,504
3,554
3,604
3,654
3,704
3,754
3,804
3,854
3,904
3,954
4,004
4,054
4,104
4,154
4,203
4,254
4,304
4,355
4,404
4,454
4,504
4,553
4,604
4,654
4,705
4,754
4,804
4,854
4,904
4,953
5,004
5,054
5,104
5,154
5,204
5,254
5,303
5,354
5,404
5,454
5,504
5,554
5,604
5,653
5,703
5,754
5,805
5,854
5,904
5,953
6,003
6,053
6,104
6,154
6,204
6,255
6,304
6,354
6,404
6,454
6,504
6,555
6,605
6,655
6,704
6,754
6,804
6,854
6,904
6,954
7,004166667
7,0545
7,104166667
7,153833333
7,203833333
7,254
7,3045
7,3545
7,404333333
7,453666667
7,503833333
7,553666667
7,603666667
7,654166667
7,704333333
7,754166667
7,803833333
7,853833333
7,9035
7,953666667
8,004
8,054166667
8,1045
8,154166667
8,203833333
8,253666667
8,3035
8,3535
8,404666667
```

P_AU :

```
81,453
77,080
71,801
67,594
63,615
60,098
56,518
53,552
50,886
47,887
45,411
43,620
41,766
40,003
38,200
36,120
35,205
33,085
32,093
30,318
29,280
28,276
26,927
26,233
25,230
24,279
23,537
22,557
21,605
21,165
20,196
19,283
18,607
17,972
17,821
17,002
16,595
15,751
15,387
14,966
13,990
13,236
13,376
12,879
12,838
11,859
11,685
11,199
10,919
10,648
10,542
9,876
9,284
9,550
8,334
8,292
7,902
7,400
7,483
7,527
7,434
6,846
6,703
6,106
5,941
5,453
5,389
4,942
5,171
4,869
4,232
4,691
3,914
4,086
3,673
3,489
3,729
2,549
2,823
2,878
2,747
1,969
1,932
2,168
2,077
1,680
1,654
1,483
1,249
0,704
1,122
0,550
0,395
0,588
0,467
0,452
0,068
0,613
0,085
-0,141
-0,492
-0,046
-0,671
-0,689
-0,867
-0,804
-0,685
-0,819
-0,724
-1,369
-1,349
-1,092
-1,433
-1,359
-1,380
-2,062
-1,655
-1,788
-1,941
-1,618
-1,867
-2,295
-2,130
-1,879
-2,138
-2,352
-2,207
-2,091
-2,306
-2,630
-2,195
-2,666
-2,763
-2,592
-2,454
-2,727
-2,793
-2,341
-2,520
-2,859
-2,72969
-2,777090167
-3,021991
-3,033841167
-2,681499833
-3,221071833
-3,349842167
-3,192631667
-3,355372333
-2,923240667
-3,365642167
-2,985651
-3,3490525
-2,8821605
-3,200531667
-3,155501667
-3,472292833
-3,622393333
-3,970784333
-3,574993
-3,311132
-3,488092667
-3,573413
-3,428842333
-3,755903833
-2,751020167
-1,678196333
-0,8755535
-0,515312167
```

**Unused defined names** (precalculated, for reference)

DataSplit:

```
=LAMBDA(RowNum;ColName;FILTER(INDIRECT('100DN'!$L$16 & "[[" & ColName & "]]");(INDIRECT('100DN'!$L$16 & "[[Temps ]]")>INDEX(INDIRECT('100DN'!$L$17);RowNum;3-'100DN'!$L$3))*(INDIRECT('100DN'!$L$16 & "[[Temps ]]")<(INDEX(INDIRECT('100DN'!$L$17);RowNum;3-'100DN'!$L$3)+INDEX(INDIRECT('100DN'!$L$17);8;3-'100DN'!$L$3)))))
```

P:

```
=LAMBDA(Col;'100DN'!DataSplit(Col;"Pressi"))
```

Tm:

```
=LAMBDA(Col;'100DN'!DataSplit(Col;"Temps ")-INDEX(INDIRECT('100DN'!$L$17);Col;3-'100DN'!$L$3))
```

P_AU:

```
=('100DN'!P(1)+'100DN'!P(2)+'100DN'!P(3)+'100DN'!P(4)+'100DN'!P(5)+'100DN'!P(6))/6
```

T_AU:

```
=('100DN'!Tm(1)+'100DN'!Tm(2)+'100DN'!Tm(3)+'100DN'!Tm(4)+'100DN'!Tm(5)+'100DN'!Tm(6))/6
```

$L$16 is the name of the table where the full dataset is located and

$L$17 is the name of the table where the limits are located for the `FILTER` function

**Notes**

`P_TH` is defined as a spilled array with `VStack` because `P_AU` and `T_AU` have variable length and to be used in a dynamic graph.

Current solving time is nearly 20 minutes. I know that not using a `LAMBDA` function within a `SCAN` function is faster, i.e. using a recursive function with relative references dragged along cells, but it does not support the variable lengths of `P_AU` and `T_AU`

Comment: Can you clarify your last statement? Why exactly does a set-up with formulas with relative references "*not support the variable lengths of `P_AU` and `T_AU`*"?

Comment: Tu be able to have a "common" cell-based formula, the `P_AU` and `T_AU` spilled array must be set in a single cell, spilling downwards.
For instance, the cell `A$1 = T_AU` and `$B$1 = P_AU`
Then, the standard formula can be put in cell `$C$1 = $B$1` and the recursive formula into `$C$2` with a relative reference to `A1`,`A2`,`B1`,`B2` and `C1`, then dragged down to a fixed length matching current `T_AU` and `P_AU` length, let's say `$C$100`. But if `T_AU` and `P_AU` change length, the span of the formulas from `$C$2` through `$C$100` would not update to reflect changes.

Comment: I noticed the use of volatile formulas (such as INDIRECT) triggers the whole workbook to update a every slight change.
I've created a non-volatile version of the formula (VBA) which improves the speed while solving and partially fix my problem, but it slows down drastically calculation of the whole workbook